# Class Cast Exception Error Fragments

Tags: java, android, exception, casting

I did this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-twitter-feed-reader/ in eclipse and moved my project to studio. Can someone please assist on what these errors mean and how I could resolve them? My logcat is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.ishonours.witsbusapp.TwitterFragment cannot be cast to android.app.ListActivity
            at com.example.ishonours.witsbusapp.TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(TwitterAsyncTask.java:24)
            at com.example.ishonours.witsbusapp.TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(TwitterAsyncTask.java:15)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This is my TwitterAsyncTask Class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.ishonours.witsbusapp.TwitterAPI;
import com.example.ishonours.witsbusapp.TwitterTweet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TwitterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<TwitterTweet>> {
    ListActivity callerActivity;

    final static String TWITTER_API_KEY = "xxx";
    final static String TWITTER_API_SECRET = "xxx";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TwitterTweet> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets = null;
        callerActivity = (ListActivity) params[1];
        if (params.length > 0) {
            TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI(TWITTER_API_KEY,TWITTER_API_SECRET);
            twitterTweets = twitterAPI.getTwitterTweets(params[0].toString());
        }
        return twitterTweets;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets) {
        ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet>(callerActivity, R.layout.twitter_tweets_list,
                        R.id.listTextView, twitterTweets);
        callerActivity.setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = callerActivity.getListView();
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        //lv.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        //lv.setBackgroundColor(callerActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.Twitter_blue));
    }
}
```

I should've mentioned that I am extremely new to this. The comments have given me some perspective of the error. I am still not quite sure how to resolve it. Any further suggestions?

This is the other class, TwitterFragment:

```
public class TwitterFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "4";

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static TwitterFragment newInstance(int menuNumber) {
        TwitterFragment fragment = new TwitterFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, menuNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public TwitterFragment() {
    }

    //i added
    final static String twitterScreenName = "WitsServices";
    final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //i added
        AndroidNetworkUtility androidNetworkUtility = new AndroidNetworkUtility();
        if (androidNetworkUtility.isConnected(this)) {
            new TwitterAsyncTask().execute(twitterScreenName,this);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Network not Available!");
        }


        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
        //        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if (null != mListener) {
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
            // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
            //mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When this line runs,

```
callerActivity = (ListActivity) params[1];
```

the code assumes that the Object at index 1 in the params array can be cast to type ListActivity. But instead it finds that the type is TwitterFragment - an incompatible cast and hence you receive this error.

Given that you are taking an arbitrary Object array as the input, the likely cause for your crash is when you create and call the AsyncTask, you must be passing in the TwitterFragment instead of passing a class of type ListActivity.

Comment: This is only half the answer; it is generically correct but does not take into account how android uses the class (the OP code does not directly call `doInBackground`)

Answer (score 0):

Gogeta's anwer is correct in that the error means that you get an instance of a class `TwitterFragment` and try to use it as a `ListActivity`; since `TwitterFragment`neither extends nor implements `ListActivity` the ClassCastException is thrown.

Checking the android [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) (Hint: always read the javadoc of the classes you use), it explains that

> The specified parameters are the parameters passed to execute(Params...)

So, somewhere in your other class, you are doing something like:

```
TwitterAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new TwitterAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute(obj1, obj2);
```

where `obj2` should be a `ListActivity` instance (probably a reference of the current activity).

In the code of your link:

```
new TwitterAsyncTask().execute(twitterScreenName,this);
```

NOTE: This code is in your post and in the link:

```
  callerActivity = (ListActivity) params[1];
  if (params.length > 0) {
```

If your code called the `execute` method passing 0 or 1 parameters, the first line would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so the check at the second line is meaningless (if that line of code is executed, we are sure that at least 2 parameters were passed). Maybe you should look for better quality tutorials.

Comment: Please could you assist further on how to resolve? I've added the other class.

Comment: Your other class extends `ListFragment`, not `ListActivity`. `ListFragment`is part of newer Android APIs. Either change the receiving class to cast to a `ListFragment`, or make your second class extend `ListActivity`. That said, I sincerely advise you to begin programming by learning the concepts, with easier (even if not so "spectacular") tutorials. Otherwise, all you do is copy the code without understanding what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. Much appreciated!